# Add id for a series of events and that breaks once the same event appears

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, partitioning

I have a dataset that looks like contains columns like `id` and `event`. What I would like to add is `desired_id` which gets incremented every times where is value `impression` in the column `event`. Could you help me how can I achieve it in SQL?

| id | event | desired_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | impression | 1 |
| 2 | click | 1 |
| 3 | purchase | 1 |
| 4 | impression | 2 |
| 5 | impression | 3 |
| 6 | click | 3 |

Comment: can share what sql you are trying and what result it is giving you or the error?

Answer (score 0):

Count(Case When event='impression' Then 1 End) Over (Order By id Rows From Unbounded Preceding To Current Row) as desired_id